# Finding Non-Matching Names in Two Different Dataframe Columns Before Joining or Merging

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, stringr

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to compare columns before doing a join in dplyr. Below are two simple dataframes. I want to join based on first and last names, however there are some spelling mistakes or different formats, such as "Elizabeth Ray" vs "Elizabeth".

I would like to compare these columns before joining. Is there a way to use a match function or set operation, like intersect, etc, to look for names that don't have matches in both columns? I just want a list of the names that are different so I can manually correct them before joining.

I would like a solution based on dplyr, tidyr, and stringr.

```
FirstNames<-c("Chris","Doug","Shintaro","Bubbles","Elsa")
LastNames<-c("MacDougall","Shapiro","Yamazaki","Murphy","Elizabeth Ray")
Pets<-c("Cat","Dog","Cat","Dog","Cat")
Names1<-data.frame(FirstNames,LastNames,Pets)

FirstNames2<-c("Chris","Doug","Shintaro","Bubbles","Elsa")
LastNames2<-c("MacDougal","Shapiro","Yamazaku","Murphy","Elizabeth")
Dwelling<-c("House","House","Apartment","Condo","House")
Names2<-data.frame(FirstNames2,LastNames2,Dwelling)
```

Comment: You may find these base R functions useful: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html

Comment: Package dplyr also has built-in set functions.  The bottom right corner of this cheat sheet details their usage in a straightforward manner: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: The are the following functions available in base R: `union`, `intersect` and `setdiff`

Comment: `dplyr::anti_join`

Comment: anti_join works best so far. Thanks!

Comment: Lol, I guess the next question is how do I create a function that will then use the results of the anti_join to replace the contents of the columns so they match. I imagine this question is far too complicated so I'll have to figure out how to phrase it within a workable example.